# MySQL refusing connection

Tags: mysql, debian

Since a few days my MySQL-Server is refusing the connection after a few hours. When trying to connect I get

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111 "Connection refused")
```

as an error message. I am able to connect again after deleting `/var/run/mysqld.sock` as well as `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0` and `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1` but after a few hours Im getting the same error message again.

I would like to show you some error logs but unfortunately they are empty and are not showing any errors.

I have a Debian 8 server which is running MySQL Version 15.1 (MariaDB 10.0.38) and Plesk 17.8.11

Comment: The first thing to do is to figure out why your log files are empty, and fix that.

Comment: move over to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the tip @RickJames, will do that